# How to implement filtering in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to create application in ember using google maps. It will looks similar to google maps, on left side I would like to have filters, on right it will be map. Lets say that my place object looks like:

```
{ name: 'Luigi', type: 'pizza', ...}
```

In filter I would like to select using checkbox what type of place I want display on map. By default, all elements are selected, and each selected type places are displayed on map.

And here start my problem. I watched peepcode, read guides, but I dont know how to start.
I think I need some `FilterController` that stores selected filter array, and in `PlacesControllers` *somehow* `content` property will watch types array from `FilterController` and return `Places` collection from model based on this array.

How to implement filtering for places in situation above?

Right now I am trying to build demo that lists places based on filter, all input welcome!

Comment: Sorry. Question added.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a computed property on the array controller that filters the array controller according to what your interface specifies:

```
App.PlacesController({
   content: [an array with your places],
   placesToDisplay: function(){
       return this.filter(function(item){
           return this.get('filter').contains(item.get('type')); //true when you want the item to be displayed.
       });
   }.property('content', 'filter'),
   filter: [] //containing the types you want to filter on.
});
```

refer to the `placesToDisplay` property in your view. And update the `filter` property. Because the `placesToDisplay` watches the `filter` property it'll rerender your view when the contents of the `filter` property changes.

What have you tried sofar? If you'd do a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I could be more specific.